# Jquery Animate executes Complete Callback early the First Time, executes normally subsequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying a simple css3 transform. I have used Deferred Object for sequencing animations. However, there is a glitch. This particular piece of code, returns the object a bit earlier than expected, the first time it is executed. It acts as expected the next time it is executed.

Essentially, during the first execution, I observe the message "Rotating Done" well before the animation is complete. During the second and third animations, the message is logged after the animation is complete.

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

```
function xRotate() {

    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    loadAllImages().promise().done(function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        $(".mp-slider").find('.card').stop(true, true).animate({  wordSpacing: 180 }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500,
            easing: "swing",
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', ' rotate3d(1,0,0,' + now + 'deg)');
                $(this).css('-moz-transform', ' rotate3d(1,0,0,' + now + 'deg)');
            }
        }).promise().done(function () {
            dfd.resolve("Rotating Done");
        });

    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: same here, but like this:  
  
`$.when(elementsToAnimateRight.animate({left: distance}, configuration.predictionAnimationDurationLeftRight),  
elementsToAnimateLeft.animate({left: -distance}, configuration.predictionAnimationDurationLeftRight)
).done( function onRemoveAnimationsFinished () {

     LOG.debug('animation.executeRemoveAnimations() >> remove right and left finished');
     executeInsertAnimations(groupId);

     distance = elementsToAnimateRight = elementsToAnimateLeft = null;  });`

sorry for this crappy inline code in comments :(